# Unable to install MySQL. Held broken packages

Tags: apt, mysql

I tried installing MySQL using

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, and I get an error saying

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I type `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1`, it says:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.1 : Depends: mysql-client-5.1 (>= 5.1.69-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
```

And when I type `mysql,` it says,

```
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I tried `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-client-5.1` but it says that

```
mysql-client is not installed so it can't be uninstalled.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: Edit your question and include the output of `sudo apt-get check`, `cat /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}` and `dpkg -l *mysql*`

Answer (score 0):

> And when I type "mysql", it says, "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect
>   to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
>   (2)"

You can login to mysql database through

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and not `mysql`

While installation going you mus get prompted for password and you have to give that password here to login.

and to fix dep issue , you might try with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```